# Firebase data update to retain other data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this current data structure on my firebase

```
{
  "bible-operators": [{
    "op-id": 0,
    "op-name": "Anonymous",
    "bcv": 101001001,
    "op-version": 1,
    "pass": "none",
    "setting1": 1,
    "setting2": 2,
    "setting3": 3,
    "setting4": 4,
    "setting5": 5,
    "setting6": 6,
    "setting7": 7,
    "bg": 1
  }, ... {
    "op-id": 4,
    "op-name": "Test User 4",
    "bcv": 101001001,
    "op-version": 1,
    "pass": "pass4",
    "setting1": 1,
    "setting2": 2,
    "setting3": 3,
    "setting4": 4,
    "setting5": 5,
    "setting6": 6,
    "setting7": 7,
    "bg": 1
  }]
}
```

I tried to make test update using this function

```
function update(op_id, nuname, nuversion, nubcv, nupass) {
  firebase.database().ref('operators/' + op_id).set({
    "op-name": nuname,
    "op-version": nuversion,
    pass: nupass,
    bcv : nubcv
  });
}
```

My expected result is to update the provided new data but retain the others that has no updates. However, after calling update, all non provided data were deleted from the database. `setting1-7` and `bg`.

How can I run the update without losing data that has no new data provided?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `firebase.database().ref('bible-operators/' + op_id).set()` replace the document, you have to use `update()` instead of `set()`.

try it:

```
firebase.database().ref('bible-operators/' + op_id).update({
    "op-name": nuname,
    "op-version": nuversion,
    pass: nupass,
    bcv : nubcv
});
```